# Compare the first letters of a list

Tags: c#, .net, string

I've a list with some strings like this:

```
List<String> data = new List<String>
{
    "marine",
    "blue",
    "SEM",
    "seven",
    "sensible",
    "six"
};
```

Now I want to compare this list with a string and add the matching items to a new list:

```
String input = "se";
List<String> newList = new List<String>;
```

The matching condition is, that the first letters should be the same (case-sensitive). In this case the newList contains:

**"seven" and "sensible"**

How is the most performant solution?

Comment: Regex seems overkill when `StartsWith()` will do.

Comment: Hard to answer this question without knowing constraints. What is the lookup/insert ratio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newList = data.Where(s => s.StartsWith(input)).ToList();
```

Comment: How is this the most performant solution? It may produce the correct results, but that isn't what the op actually asked

Comment: @Sayse: one can not answer that question as stated.  So take the win.

Comment: @Dan-o - I agree Dan-o, hence why I have voted to close